# memory corruption when using c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, boost

```
template<typename V>
class Counter 
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Counter<V> > {

 public:
  Counter(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, uint32_t update_interval)
    : current_load_(std::numeric_limits<V>::min()), 
      last_load_(std::numeric_limits<V>::min()),
      max_load_value_(std::numeric_limits<V>::max()),
      update_timer_(CreateTimer(io_service)),
      update_interval_(update_interval) {
  }

  void Start() {
    update_timer_->Start(boost::bind(&SingleLoadCounter::UpdateLoad, 
        this->shared_from_this(), _1),
        boost::posix_time::milliseconds(update_interval_));
  }

  void Stop() {
    update_timer_->Stop();
  }

 private:
  void UpdateLoad(std::function<void(bool redial)> callback) {
    {
      boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
      last_load_ = current_load_;
      current_load_ = 0;
    }
    callback(true);
  }

  V current_load_;
  V last_load_;
  V max_load_value_;

  TimerPtr update_timer_;
  uint32_t update_interval_;

  boost::mutex mutex_;
};
```

After creating instance of this class in `boost::shared_ptr` address `update_timer_.px` is valid. But then when in Stop() I call method on `update_timer_` I get Segmentation fault, because `update_timer_.px` points on the wrong place.

Addresses of `update_timer_.px`:

- In constructor of `Counter`:  0x1b15b50
- In method `Stop`: 0x1b15b3000000000

Running it under gdb, I saw that 0x1b15b3 was the address of `update_timer_.pn`. So somehow `this->update_timer_.px` moved on few bits forward

All this was done on Release target. On Debug it works fine. Class `Counter` was used as a `shared_prt` with template type `uint32_t`

```
System: Ubuntu 10.4 x64, gcc: 4.7.2
```

Comment: in Start() function it works well?

Comment: Mostly yes. But sometimes it fails here too. It even change its behavior when I add some printfs.

Comment: We need more information. Most likely you're running into [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (could originate somewhere else). But we don't even know what `TimerPtr` is here, so we can't tell. Make it a SSCCE, and run it under valgrind/helgrind